# Iterm2 over full screen apps, like quake/guake

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm2, macos-sierra

Is there any way to make ITerm2 overlay over full screen apps just like quake/guake alternatives on Linux?

I don't want Iterm to slide to desktop where it was initially open when i press hotkey, i want it to overlay over the desktop i am currently in.

I know its possible to do it in macOS because other apps like Alfred do that but can't figure out if Iterm2 supports this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preference -> Advanced -> Hide iTerm2 from the dock ... => set to Yes

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have that turned on, it hides it from the dock and from cmd+tab but it still transfers me to desktop where Iterm was initially opened. I don't want that. I want it to overlay/drop on any current desktop

Comment: Under preference -> profile -> window -> space : set to all spaces. Give it a try

Comment: Finally! It works, thanks. 
Edit: Edit your original answer to add this, so i can mark it answered.

Comment: In 2020 and iTerm 3 beta, this is no longer found by searching for "hide" - you can find it by searching for "Exclude" or "Exclude from dock". It is now located in Preferences > Appearance > General.

Comment: I had to toggle "Exclude from Dock and ..." in Preferences > Appearance > General otherwise it would still move me to another screen